# Is there wubi for Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: wubi, 13.10

Is there a wubi installer for Ubuntu 13.10 x64?

Answer (score 2):

According to my research, Wubi support (officially) was discontinued from 13.04 and onwards.  Wubi is not available for 13.10 as a result.  Wubi is only available still with 12.04 LTS according to the Wubi documentation and windows installer pages.

An alternative would be to install VirtualBox inside of your Windows installation and then install Ubuntu to a VirtualBox Virtual Machine, which would run Ubuntu inside of a virtual machine, which in turn is inside Windows.  This however requires you to boot up to Windows first before using VirtualBox to access Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. Sorry. But nope. It's for 12.04 LTS only. And I would not reccommend installing ubuntu or any os/distro from wubi (if you could) because it often leads to problems like windows won't start. I would say use UNetBootin to put the ISO on a flash drive or use InfraRecorder to put it on a disc. A walkthrough on how to install ubuntu can be found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Wubi 13.10 here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.10/wubi.exe). It's been tried by others, and seems to work without a hitch, but please remember that it's officially unsupported.

Comment: 404 page. dead link

Comment: @emrah Ubuntu 13.10 is now end of life and therefore not recommended. Like other EOL releases it is available at http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/saucy/