# Installing ubuntu-13.10 on Win7

Tags: installation, wubi

I just want to make sure I do this right. I downloaded unetbootin-windows and also ubuntu-13.10-desktop iso. I ran unetbootin and chose USB and it seemed to create folders on my USB drive along with the WUBI.EXE.

But now I'm not sure what the next step is. I want a dual boot system. OR to run Ubuntu alongside Windows. When I ran WUBI was given the option to reboot now or later. What will this do?

RON

Comment: did you want to install ubuntu 13.10 through WUBI,please don't do this.It causes several problems.Try to install ubuntu along with windows on your HDD.

Comment: Then I'm not sure what to do. I have it on my USB. I think it's installed but it's not clear. Do I reboot and do something? I have the ISO and, as I mentioned, unetbootin. SO...what do I do, specifically? To be clear, I don't want to do any specific thing regarding Ubuntu apart from being able to run it as an OS.

Comment: did you want to install ubuntu 13.10 on your hard-disk?

Comment: Yes, I mean... does it make a difference? HD vs USB?

Comment: first format all your USB contents and then try unetbootin software.Hard disk was a storage device,already attached to your pc,it has a maximum of 2TB and a minimum of 100gb(approx).But usb is portable storage device,it has a maximum of 64GB and min of 1GB(approx).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

To clarify what has happened:

(It is important to know that your hard disk is divided up into "volumes", aka "Partitions". Right now, you probably just have one partition, which is dedicated to your Windows OS. Your goal is a full Ubuntu installation, which would reduce the size of the Windows partition so it doesn't take up your entire hard disk, and add two more partitions for Ubuntu.)

You have installed Ubuntu using Wubi, a program that installs Ubuntu "within" Windows. When you reboot, which you should at this point, you will see the option to boot Ubuntu, which has been installed to a virtual filesystem within the Windows partition. See [What's the difference between Wubi and a regular "alongside Windows" installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/615/whats-the-difference-between-wubi-and-a-regular-installation)

If you run in to serious, unfixable problems with this, you should uninstall the Wubi version of Ubuntu by booting Windows and uninstalling the `Ubuntu` program from "Add/Remove Programs" (keep in mind that, while this appears to be treating Ubuntu as if it were a Windows program, it is more complicated than that.) Then, boot from your USB thumb drive and do a full installation of Ubuntu. If your computer doesn't boot from the USB key automatically, you may have to change the BIOS settings by entering into setup upon boot, or bring up a one-time boot menu if your computer has it and use that to boot from the USB thumb drive.

Comment: THANKS (to you both). I'll let you know what happens on Sunday.

Comment: When I run WUBI I get two buttons: DEMO and LEARN MORE. Demo says I should reboot with the CD in the tray. SO, what did I do "installing" it on a USB drive?

Comment: If you were booted in Windows for the entire time during the installation, then you used Wubi ([see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wubi_%28Ubuntu_installer%29)) to install Ubuntu inside Windows, which [theoretically isn't possible since 13.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/360583/is-there-wubi-for-ubuntu-13-10). Boot into Windows, uninstall the Ubuntu program using Add/Remove programs in the Control Panel, and boot from the USB disk to do a full Ubuntu installation.