# Cannot download the metalink and therefore the ISO

Tags: 13.10, wubi, system-installation

I am installing ubuntu 13.10 desktop version on my windows 7. I want to remove my old OS which is Windows 7 and replace  from ubuntu. I am trying to installing it by wubi.exe. But it is shows error while installing. The error is

**Cannot download the metalink and therefore the ISO. For more information , Please see the log file**

Please suggest any better way to do that.
Thanks

Comment: Take a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/360583/is-there-wubi-for-ubuntu-13-10

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wubi Installer Can't Find Metalink](http://askubuntu.com/questions/202217/wubi-installer-cant-find-metalink)

Comment: what's wrong with using Wubi? It always worked great for me and save me a lot of time and headaches! I wonder who makes such stupid decisions and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Wubi anymore for 13.10 and will not be for future versions.

Also, Wubi it was not used to install Ubuntu to replace Windows, but to coexist for people that want to test and not alter their partiction scheme / filesystems.

You need to boot the normal installation/live version and choose to remove Windows and install Ubuntu (it will be one of the choices).

To install Ubuntu (the way you mentioned and the official way) please download [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) from the official link, burn it on a DVD or make an USB stick with [Pen Drive](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) as the official docs recommend for USB install.

Reboot your computer and start from DVD/USB and follow the install procedure which is only a few simple questions asked.

Also the documentation has everything covered about the installation, it's not useful to reproduce them on other sites. [Ubuntu Desktop Installation Documentation](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest).

Comment: There is a Wubi in 13.10, but it's not officially unsupported.

Comment: I want to replace my old os. So please suggest me any better ubuntu  verion and also tell me how to install that.

Comment: It will not be supported anymore.

Comment: you have more in my answer

Comment: @ iMadalin Whwn i tried to install ubuntu 13.10 from usb by botting option then it show me error something like that missing operating system.

Comment: Did you use [Universal USB Installer – Easy as 1 2 3](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) from Pendrive to create the USB? If you have problems with the computer to boot from USB, really try with a DVD.

Comment: @Gabb3 [Actually, Wubi still exists, still ships with new versions of Ubuntu, and remains for the most part supported, though people are less encouraged to use Wubi installs.](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7497/wubi-discussion-again-supported-here-on-ask-ubuntu-13-04-and-later/7596#7596) See [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/449526/22949) for a bit more information.