# Problem in installing ubuntu 14.0.4 LTS

Tags: 14.04

I have downloaded iso file of ubuntu 14.0.4 LTS, but when i do open wubi to install from windows it shows an error "cannot download metalink and therefore the iso" .Please help me solve this problem

Comment: WUBI is no longer maintained or recomended tho.

Comment: You should make a bootable disc and install from that.

Comment: wubi does not work on windows 8. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot download the metalink and therefore the ISO](http://askubuntu.com/questions/425978/cannot-download-the-metalink-and-therefore-the-iso)