# 14.04.2 installation is interrupted by error message

Tags: 14.04

During the final stage of installing ubuntu 14.04.2 installation is interrupted by the message 'Cannot download the metalink and therefore the ISO'

Comment: Are you installing using WUBI?

Comment: 'yes, i am using WUBI'

Comment: Take a look here http://askubuntu.com/questions/425978/cannot-download-the-metalink-and-therefore-the-iso.  Hence the question will be closed as duplicate.

Comment: Do not use Wubi. Download the ISO and create a bootable USB/DVD.