# Wubi: Cannot download metalink and therefore the ISO (Change?)

Tags: 14.04, wubi

Lots of people in the community have had problems with the Wubi already. I also have those problems. But after checking the logfiles of the problem, I had an idea, and I hope that someone can help me with it.

For example, the logfile shows that the Wubi tries to download file from [here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-i386.metalink), but the thing is that it has updated to 14.04.3.

So my question is, is there anyway to change the link that it requests, or to talk to the developers about this?

Comment: It is not a bug, but wubi is supported no more.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot download the metalink and therefore the ISO](http://askubuntu.com/questions/425978/cannot-download-the-metalink-and-therefore-the-iso)

Comment: I mean that we can make it fix the problem, probably, if we can really change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The devs must know the issue because of an [existing bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/wubi/+bug/1367071) for 14.04.1. 14.04.1 was the first point release where the devs forgot(?) to update the links.

IMHO there are the following solutions to fix this:

1. You avoid Wubi (recommended).
2. You wait until devs will fix this (Maybe, this will never happen)
3. You change the file mentioned in bug report by your own. (Maybe, this solution is too difficult for you).
4. You use [a workaround for 14.04.1](http://ubuntu-with-wubi.blogspot.co.at/2014/10/installing-ubuntu-14041-with-wubi.html) published by bcbc, which works for 14.04.3, too. Thanks to bcbc.
5. You trust unofficial, unsigned but fully fixed versions by hakuna_matata which you can find [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6uqomp8l1frcd1y/AAAhSCimTaYE-94egbmc1X_na?dl=0). Thanks to hakuna_matata.

Comment: But you're sure that they are those links? It seems like they cant reach the destination on my computer. They just load and stopped.

Comment: Those links are not working for you ?
http://ubuntu-with-wubi.blogspot.co.at/2014/10/installing-ubuntu-14041-with-wubi.html
and 
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6uqomp8l1frcd1y/AAAhSCimTaYE-94egbmc1X_na?dl=0

edit: Sorry, I had some troubles with the editor.

Comment: Isnt the first one blogspot or something? The second one is still  not Okay.

Comment: The first one should link to the blog of bcbc, the second one to the dropbox folder of hakuna_matata

Comment: Well, I acknowledge that. Anyway, thank you, even if they still dont work.

Comment: I found the link to the dropbox folder in this post of hakuna_matata: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2251986&p=13162861#post13162861 It works for me. Maybe, the reason is a pop-up blocker of your browser.