# Ubuntu installer wants to download itself again

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, wubi

I already downloaded the appropriate ISO for my laptop, it was about 1GB. I partitioned 30GB for Ubuntu, extracted the ISO into a folder on my Windows drive, ran the wubi.exe file in the main folder, set it to install in my new U partition for Ubuntu, and halfway through installation it tries to download the ISO that I already just downloaded! Is there any way to install it offline? Is it not finding the other contents in the folder? I'm in a hotel with 1Mbps internet right now, so I'm not able to do another 1GB file.

Comment: Which Ubuntu version did you download ? 14.04(.3) ? 15.04 ? For 14.04 your question is a possible duplicate of  http://askubuntu.com/q/661729/386067

Comment: I don't think 1GB is enough... I don't know the sizes at the moment, but what you downloaded could be just a network installer. Also, to my knowledge Wubi isn't supported anymore. I'd suggest burning a DVD with an image. It's the best way not to rely on installing from within Windumb. ;)

Comment: @Peter Nerlich: The size of the desktop iso is about 1GB comparing with  http://releases.ubuntu.com/trusty or http://releases.ubuntu.com/vivid column "size".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another way if u have a USB stick or a dvd. burn the iso to the dvd or make a bootable usb using [rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) and then install it.
[Here](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html) is a great tutorial to get ur things done.

Comment: I don't have a physical USB stick on me, before when installing Ubuntu on another machine a while ago, it never required to download the ISO. Is there any other way?