# Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS WUBI won't run the Installer

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, wubi

As far as the wiki says wubi.exe should eventually let me install UBUNTU like a Windows program, however it only gives me the option or rather the notice to boot into the demo mode and make the installation from there. What do?

Comment: What wiki? Wubi installs aren't supported since some years back.

Comment: I followed a [german unofficial wiki](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/WUBI#Wubi-installieren) which explicitly states that the article has been tested with 14.04 but it also says so [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide). So you're saying i have to boot into the CD and install on a free partition?

Comment: The wubi  guide says the latest supported version is 12.10. There is no mention of 14.04 there.

Comment: A similar question was answered for 12.04: http://askubuntu.com/a/125163 but be aware. Newer Wubi version are not maintained and therefore not recommended. There are other issues like http://askubuntu.com/q/661729/386067

Comment: @ngng if you made an answer of that i'd flag it solved or my question should rather be marked as dublicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar question was answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/125163) for 12.04 but be aware. Newer Wubi versions are not maintained and therefore not recommended. There are other issues like [that one](https://askubuntu.com/q/661729).