# Error during the installation of Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, wubi

I have Ubuntu 14.04 but whenever I try to install it from a DVD or just by the Wubi setup itself I get an error message saying:

> An Error occurred:
>   Cannot download the metalink and therefore the ISO
>   For more information, please see the log file:
>   c:\users\rajatm~1\appdata\local\temp\wubi-14.04-rev286.log

I am just a beginner to Ubuntu so please guide me. I would be very thankful to this community.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: Avoid Wubi or try a [community supported version](https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi/wiki#releases). The official Wubi version for 14.04 uses outdated download links.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug [source](https://bugs.launchpad.net/wubi/+bug/383752).
This issue is already solved in the site. Please search before asking a question.
Check these for solution
[Wubi Installer Can't Find Metalink](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202217/wubi-installer-cant-find-metalink)
[Is there wubi for Ubuntu 13.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360583/is-there-wubi-for-ubuntu-13-10)
[Windows installer for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS onwards](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449486/windows-installer-for-ubuntu-14-04-lts-onwards)